# Как передать данные из EditText в ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android

Нужно передать данные в `ShareActionProvider` (для возможности реализации кнопки поделиться)
Но данные взятые с  `onCreate()` не видны во внешнем методе

Как реализовать передачу с `EditText`?

Код Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
        return true;
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        // не видит параметр editText c onCreate()
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText);
        return shareIntent;
    }
```

Разметка:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: прошу прощение за форматирование кода не могу понять как на stackoverflow вставить код чтоб он нормально отображался

Answer (score 3):

**Во-первых**, можно сделать `editText` приватным полем класса `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Во-вторых**, можно вызывать `findViewById` сразу в методе `createShareIntent`:

```
private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: а зачем его  делать приватным ? private EditText editText;

Answer (score 2):

Создайте поле:

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private EditText edittext = null; //вот это поле
```

Теперь в `onCreate`:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

И теперь в `createShareIntent`

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText.toString());
```